# Am I using marionettejs properly?

Tags: marionette

hi i've been using backbonejs for almost 2 years now and am just starting out on marionettejs with my first app at [this website](http://corongaleri.com.ph/?pg=coron_tours_custom_tour).

the reason for my question is that in my app i have a Layout with a 2 composite view rendered as dropdown list and table (which updates itself whenever we change the selection on the dropdown list).

what i did was for the "change" event on my dropdown list, i have an MyApp.vent.trigger() which i have a listener at the MyApp.addInitializer() function that updates the other compositeview (the table below the dropdown list). actually for the whole app i have almost 6 of this triggers inside itemViews and compositeViews and listeners are inside the addInitializer() for some of the other functions.

i just want to know if i did this right? or is this how dev in marionettejs normally is?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that's the recommended idea. However, you don't necessarily need to use the top-level `vent` attribute: each sub-app and view has their own (scoped) event manager. In addition, you don't necessarily need to add the listener in an `addInitializer`.

Here's an example (from my [Marionette book](https://leanpub.com/marionette-gentle-introduction)):

- trigger an event at the view scope: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_view.js#L15 This uses the `triggers` hash, but you could also do `this.trigger("my:event")` from within the view, like here: https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_view.js#L29
- listening to the events (and retriggering them if necessary): https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_controller.js#L48 and https://github.com/davidsulc/marionette-gentle-introduction/blob/master/assets/js/apps/contacts/list/list_controller.js#L38

Hope this helps !

Comment: thanks david, i think i'm starting to get the idea. i can call any event from any view and have any other view catch/listen to that event right?

Comment: can i do this with backbone on requirejs? what i did with my backbon app  was trigger the event on a view, then have it listened/triggered to its parent, and repeat it until i get to the main view that i needed to act on it. (not like what i did with mrionette, where i have a single trigger from a view, then have that target view listen to it directly.)

Comment: sorry i misunderstood. i can only listen to these events from somewhere i can access the components doing the trigger right? :)

Comment: Yes, they're scoped, so you can only listen from where you have access to a reference of the object tirggering the event (which allows you to have several scoped using the same event name). But you can also retrigger an event to pass it on to a higher level.